# Hortonworks 2.5 ACID Insert in hive hangs

Tags: hiveql

I am using HDP 2.5. I want to perform a delete operation from a Hive table. I have created a table with the following command:

```
 hive> create table test (x int, y string) clustered by (x) into 2    buckets stored as ORC tblproperties ("transactional" = "true");
```

OK
Time taken: 0.148 seconds

Further, I have set the following Hive properties:

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=false;
```

Then on, I am doing a test insert into the hive table leveraging the following command:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,a);
```

Unfortunately my Hive CLI shell is getting hung and I have to issue Ctrl + C command to get out of the shell. May I know why is this happening please? Is it due to the fact that my Hive schema / database contains a mixture of ACID and non-ACID tables ? Any suggestion to resolve this problem will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance !